# Play music on Background and use Media Player and video view

Tags: java, android

In my application I use a video view and media player. I would like the user to be able to listen to their music while on my app. For the media player I already know that we simply shouldn't initialize them, but for the video view I can't find any solution ...
Ideally, I would like the user to have their music and application sounds. Any idea for me?
Thank you in advance !

Comment: sounds like you need foregroundService. withhelp foregroundservice you will able to manage your mediaplayer

Comment: thank you, have you an example on a website ?

Comment: check this for example https://androidwave.com/foreground-service-android-example/